# Set center for google map by using yii2-google-maps-markers

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, yii2

I'm using [yii2-google-maps-markers](https://github.com/yii2mod/yii2-google-maps-markers) for my webste.
It works fine.
I want to create a search engine, so I want to change the center value of google map after searched result shown.
I could change the center position but all makers removed.
How I can change center by using js with a specified address without removing makers.
My code is below:

view.php

```
 <?php
    echo GoogleMaps::widget([
        'userLocations' => $locat,
        'googleMapsUrlOptions' => [
            'key' => Yii::$app->params['GOOGLE_API_KEY'],
        ],
        'googleMapsOptions' => [
        ],
        'wrapperHeight' => '350px',
  ]);
?>
```

and current solution

```
<script type="text/javascript">

// Run function after page loaded
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    show_map_theo_address("some where, America");
}, false);

    // This is the minimum zoom level that we'll allow
    function show_map_theo_address(address) {
        var geocoder, vitri;
        var minZoomLevel = 15;
        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        if (geocoder) {
            geocoder.geocode({
                'address': address
            }, function (results, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    if (status != google.maps.GeocoderStatus.ZERO_RESULTS) {
                        vitri = results[0].geometry.location;
                        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
                            zoom: minZoomLevel,
                            center: new google.maps.LatLng(results[0].geometry.location.lat(), results[0].geometry.location.lng()),
                            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                        });
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }

    }
```

But it does not work.
Please help.

Comment: what mean does not work  .. you have error (check in browser console ) or other?

Comment: No error, but all makers were removed. I do not want this.

Answer (score 1):

You should separate the logic .. a first part for show the map  and all the markers a second part for get the new marker position and set the center

This beacuse you create (recreate) the maps when you use the actual show_map_theo_address function

for avoid the markers deletion you should

create a global var map

```
<script>
  var map;
  ......
```

move the creation of the map outside the function show_map_theo_address()

```
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
      zoom: minZoomLevel,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(YourInitialCenterLat, YourInitialCenterLng),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });
```

inside the function  show_map_theo_address() use setCenter

```
// This is the minimum zoom level that we'll allow
function show_map_theo_address(address) {
    var geocoder, vitri;
    var minZoomLevel = 15;
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    if (geocoder) {
        geocoder.geocode({
            'address': address
        }, function (results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                if (status != google.maps.GeocoderStatus.ZERO_RESULTS) {
                    vitri = results[0].geometry.location;
                      map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(results[0].geometry.location.lat(), results[0].geometry.location.lng()));
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks scaisEdge. I'using yii2 widget, so I think I can not do a global initial as same as the first part. The first part has already done by "echo GoogleMaps::widget...". If I was wrong, please teach me.

Comment: I don't know the Yii2 Widgte for google Maps  .. i use directly  .. google maps  in javascript (for me is more ieasy)  .. i have suggested  the logic .. and you should adapt to you need .. when  try not recreate the map in your function ..  hope this is useful

Comment: Thanks you. I"ll try creating gg map by js again.